# Set theory reverse engineering question.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

First we define a new operator ∩m as follows:

For some set of sets T and some set S, T ∩m S = { t ∩ S | t ∈ T }.

For example, if T1 = { , {1}, {2}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}} and ∅ S1 = {1, 3, 4}, then T1 ∩m S1 = { , {1}, {1, 3}}, ∅ because:

∅ ∩ S1 = , ∅
{1} ∩ S1 = {1},
{2} ∩ S1 = , ∅
{1, 2} ∩ S1 = {1}, and
{1, 3} ∩ S1 = {1, 3}.

Now we define a new term split for some set of sets T and some set S:
T splits S if ℘(S) ⊆ T ∩m S

For example, for the value of T1 given above and S2 = {1, 2}, T1 splits S2.

Let T3 = { ∅, {0}, {1}, {0, 1}, {1, 2}, {0, 1, 2} }. There are 6 distinct sets ∅ S such that T3
splits S. List them.

Wouldn't distinct sets of S be ℘(T3) - {∅}, {{0}}, {{1}}, {{0,1}}, {{1,2}}, {{0,1,2}} - since they would fit both requirements T ∩m S and the ℘(S) requirement? Am I incorrect in my reasoning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$T_3$ does not split any of your sets. Take your $\{\{0\}\}$, for instance. Its subsets are $\varnothing$ and $\{\{0\}\}$, so $T_3$ splits it if and only if there are sets $X,Y\in T_3$ such that $X\cap\{\{0\}\}=\varnothing$ and $Y\cap\{\{0\}\}=\{\{0\}\}$. Now $\varnothing\in T_3$, and $\varnothing\cap\{\{0\}\}=\varnothing$, so we can take $X=\varnothing$, but $Y$ is another story: there is no $Y\in T_3$ such that $Y\cap\{\{0\}\}=\{\{0\}\}$. To see this, note that $Y\cap\{\{0\}\}=\{\{0\}\}$ iff $\{\{0\}\}\subseteq Y$ iff $\{0\}\in Y$, and $\{0\}$ is not a member of any $Y\in T_3$.

The sets that $T_3$ splits are $\varnothing$, $\{0\}$, $\{1\}$, $\{2\}$, $\{0,1\}$, and $\{0,2\}$. For instance, $T_3$ splits $\{0,1\}$ because the subsets of $\{0,1\}$ are $\varnothing,\{0\},\{1\}$, and $\{0,1\}$, and $\varnothing\cap\{0,1\}=\varnothing$, $\{0\}\cap\{0,1\}=\{0\}$, $\{1\}\cap\{0,1\}=\{1\}$, and $\{0,1\}\cap\{0,1\}$, where the first set in each of these four intersections is a member of $T_3$. For a more complicated example, $T_3$ splits $\{0,2\}$ because the subsets of $\{0,2\}$ are $\varnothing,\{0\},\{2\}$, and $\{0,2\}$, and $\varnothing\cap\{0,2\}=\varnothing$, $\{0\}\cap\{0,2\}=\{0\}$, $\{1,2\}\cap\{0,2\}=\{2\}$, and $\{0,1,2\}\cap\{0,2\}=\{0,2\}$, where again the first set in each of these four intersections is a member of $T_3$.

Comment: Thanks prof. Brian! Can you offer some criticism to my question : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629596/proving-carefully-that-if-s-is-bounded-above-then-it-contains-its-supremum